# How to reference SAM Conditions in the AWS:IAM:Role Statement Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I understand that SAM is built on top of CloudFormation, and there are some facilities within SAM to make it easier to construct the stack template.

I created a SAM Condition like:

```yaml
    Conditions:
      ProductTag: !Equals
        - 'aws:ResourceTag/Joba:Product'
        - !Ref Product
      EnvironmentTag: !Equals
        - 'aws:ResourceTag/Joba:Environment'
        - !Ref Environment
      TagsPolicy: !And
        - !Condition ProductTag
        - !Condition EnvironmentTag
```

And I tried to reference the `TagsPolicy` in the `AWS::IAM::Role` policies (last line).

```yaml
      DownloadBrokerageNotesStateMachineExecutionRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - !Sub states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
                Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          Path: "/"
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: LambdaExecute
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                    Resource: 
                      - !GetAtt RicoRobotAuthenticateFunction.Arn
                    Condition: TagsPolicy
```

Running `sam validate --link` gives me:

```
template.yaml is a valid SAM Template. This is according to basic SAM Validation
W8001 Condition TagsPolicy not used.
```

But running `sam deploy`, throws the following error:

```
Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: d215f541-4f16-4050-ac48-04bda830e9dc; Proxy: null)
The following resource(s) failed to create: [DownloadBrokerageNotesStateMachineExecutionRole]. Rollback requested by user.
```

How can I reference the `TagsPolicy` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Condition` key has several distinct usages in a template.  You're mixing them up a bit.

1. The template's top-level `Condition` section defines rules governing the [conditional creation of resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html). The conditions are then optionally applied within resource definitions, also using the `Condition` key.  CloudFormation evaluates these conditions at deploy-time, deploying only those resources where the condition is true.  This isn't what you want.
2. IAM policy statements accept an optional, unrelated `Condition` element to [narrow the policy's applicability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html). Define the [policy conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval) in the statement itself.  The conditions are part of the policy definition and are applied at run-time when the policy is evaluated.

```yaml
DownloadBrokerageNotesStateMachineExecutionRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  # Meaning #1:  Applies a defined condition.  Role is created only if the condition is true.
  # Not what you want
  Condition: IsProduction
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service:
              - !Sub states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
          Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: LambdaExecute
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              Resource:
                - !GetAtt RicoRobotAuthenticateFunction.Arn
              # Meaning #2: Defines the conditions under which the IAM policy applies.
              # This is what you want
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  "aws:ResourceTag/Joba:Product": !Ref Product
                  "aws:ResourceTag/Joba:Environment": !Ref Environment
```

Comment: Yeah, got it. I'm getting the hang of it. Lots of pieces to put together.
Thanks.